# Mapping PUMA Codes to TIGER/line shapefiles

Tags: data-request, data.gov, us-census, programming

I downloaded PUMA mapping shapefiles for California from [TIGER/line](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_puma.html) and am able to use `R` packages `maptools, mapproj, and ggplot2` to plot maps of California with each PUMA outline as a border. My goal is to match the PUMA mapping files to ACS data I have for CA to create heat maps, (such as average income per PUMA).

However, the shapefiles have id numbers which are number 0-264 identifying each PUMA like so:

```
pumas.points
        long      lat order  hole piece  id group
1: -122.6464 38.59859     1 FALSE     1   0   0.1
2: -122.6447 38.60216     2 FALSE     1   0   0.1
3: -122.6447 38.60322     3 FALSE     1   0   0.1
4: -122.6418 38.60548     4 FALSE     1   0   0.1
5: -122.6391 38.60927     5 FALSE     1   0   0.1
```

`range(as.numeric(pumas.points$id))`
`[1]   0 264`

`length(unique(pumas.points$id))`
`[1] 265`

This data I am able to map with ggplot2. For my ACS data, instead of id numbers 0-264 I have each 5 digit PUMA code, like so.

```
test
 PUMA10   percent
```

`1:  08513 0.3647587`
  `2:  07301 0.7857143`
  `3:  01903 0.5035714`
  `4:  06509 0.5312500`
  `5:  06506 0.7687927`

Each PUMA10 code corresponds to one of the PUMAs in the points file created from the .shp file.

```
length(unique(test$PUMA10))
```

`[1] 265`

However, I have so far been unable to find a file mapping the 1-3 digit id values assigned in the shapefiles with the 5-digit PUMA10 codes assigned in the ACS data download. My goal is to be able to create maps similar to [proximity one](http://proximityone.com/puma/puma2010ca.htm). If anyone knows if such a file exists it would be most appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 4 variables you are leaving out of the shapefile that was imported to R.

1. `STATEFP10` is the 2-digit FIPS code for the state.
2. `PUMACE10` is the 5-digit FIPS code for the 2010 PUMA within a state.
3. `AFFGEOID10` is the full GEOID that is unique across all levels of geography.
4. `GEOID10` is the GEOID that uniquely identifies a geographic boundary within a specific summary level. This variable (or AFFGEOID10) should be used to match between different sources. To re-create this variable in the ACS PUMS data, concatenate the State FIPS code with 2010 PUMA code (make sure that it is a string/character variable with a length of 7).

Comment: Thank you so much. Adding the IDvar argument to the below call solved my problem. Thank you!                             `readShapePoly(paste0(path,"cb_2015_06_puma10_500k.shp"), IDvar = "PUMACE10")`